# Difference between "no" and "not"

Tags: negation

Please tell me which of the following sentence is correct and why?

> - It is no good asking him for help.
> - It is not good asking him for help.

Please explain the usage of *no* and *not*. Are they adverbs or adjectives or something else?

Answer (score 4):

They are both correct but have different meanings. *It's no good (doing something)* .. is an idiom that means *there is no point or use in doing it; you are wasting your time doing it*. For example: *It's no good asking him for help. He's too busy with his own work.*

Similar examples from Google:

> It's no good asking – no one knows what it is and where it comes from.
>
> It's no good asking them anything, they couldn't care less!
>
> It's no good asking me. I haven't got a clue.

On the other hand, *It's not good (doing something) ..* means that it's not a good idea to do it. For example: *It's not good asking him for help; he will think you are incompetent.*

More Google examples:

> It's not good asking that, here on the internet, because there are many people, who will try take you down.
>
> It's not good asking to move deadlines because, as a freelancer, you lose credibility.
>
> It's not good asking strangers health related problems, better consult the professionals.

Comment: I'd say "It's not good *to ask*" rather than "It's not good asking."